# Twitch Bot Receiving PRIVMSG when chat message sent

Tags: c#, .net, twitch

I am attempting to write a bot for my twitch channel in C#.NET and it connects successfully, but when I send a message in the public chat I get the following:

> :connorwrightkappa!connorwrightkappa@connorwrightkappa.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #connorwrightkappa :test

Connection code:

```
tcpClient = new TcpClient("irc.chat.twitch.tv", 6667);
reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
writer = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());

writer.WriteLine("PASS " + password + Environment.NewLine
            + "NICK " + username + Environment.NewLine + 
            "USER " + username + " 8 * :" + username);

writer.Flush();

writer.WriteLine("JOIN #" + channelName);

writer.Flush();
```

username is the username of the bot

password is the oauth token for the bot

channelName is the name of the channel that the bot should join

Timer1 Tick:

```
if (!tcpClient.Connected)
{

    Reconnect();

}


if (tcpClient.Available > 0 || reader.Peek() >= 0)
{

    var message = reader.ReadLine();
    aLabel.Text += $"\r\n{message}";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRIVMSG is a public chat message on twitch. Don't ask me why, but it is...